# Jquery LightSlider does not resume playback after thumbnail is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I realised that lightSlider does not have a resume playback function and will stop playing once any slide is clicked. Is there any way we can add in this functionality?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var slider = $('#demo').lightSlider({
        item:1,
        slideMargin:0,
        pause:8000,
        enableTouch:true,
        auto:true,
        loop:true,
        controls:false,
        pauseOnHover: true,
    });

    $('#demo').parent().on('mouseenter',function(){
        slider.pause();
    });

     $('#demo').parent().on('mouseleave',function(){
        slider.play();
    });
});
```

I tried adding a resume play functionality with the mouseleave function but it does not work on mobile. Will appreciate if any one of you gurus has any suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

i Found the solution. 
01.use this lightSlider.js file link : http://raw.githack.com/sachinchoolur/lightslider/1.1.2/src/js/lightslider.js

02.script on the page:

```
$(window).load(function(){

$('#lightSlider').lightSlider({

item: 4,
auto:true,
slideMargin: 2,
loop :true,
pause: 4000,
speed: 1000,
onAfterSlide: function () {
    $('#lightSlider iframe').remove();
    $('#lightSlider li').removeClass('hasIframe');
}
});

});
```

found from this